# Linking libqxt in a Qt5 application on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, libqxt

I have a problem with linking **libqxt** in a **Qt5** application.

I write a code like in example in documentation but I have errors.

```
QxtGlobalShortcut* shortcut = new QxtGlobalShortcut(this);
connect(shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(newScreenshoot()));
shortcut->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+F12"));
```

I'm using **Qt 5.0.1**:

```
damian@damian-Lenovo-B560:~$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.0.1 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

And latest **libqxt-dev** from **Ubuntu 13.04** repository.

I have following linker errors:

```
/home/damian/Dokumenty/Programowanie/QShot/mainwindow.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to `QxtGlobalShortcut::QxtGlobalShortcut(QObject*)'
/home/damian/Dokumenty/Programowanie/QShot/mainwindow.cpp:22: error: undefined reference to `QxtGlobalShortcut::setShortcut(QKeySequence const&)'
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't *link* libqxt. Only including the headers of a library is only one of two steps, linking it is the second. However, I don't know what to do exactly to link this library, maybe have a look at the documentation.

Comment: I've added to my *.pro file CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui as said in the documentation.

Comment: Can you show me the qmake output please? Did you also try it with Qt4? Maybe qxt is only compatible with Qt4 (or maybe this particular build of the library is build with Qt4...)

Comment: I just found out that libqxt itself *is* compatible with Qt5. But according to [this package dependency listing](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/libqxt-dev/0.6.1-6) it seems like the package provided in Ubuntu is compiled and linked against Qt4. This makes it impossible to use with Qt5. So you have to build it manually, I guess... :(

Comment: Manually build isn't soo horrible. (: I will try and post back my progress. (:

Comment: Unfortunetly I cannot build libqxt for linux, I encountered this error http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/issue/37/building-libqxt-on-linux-and-qt5

Comment: According to [the guide for porting from Qt4 to Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/sourcebreaks.html): `Qt::qInstallMsgHandler() is deprecated, so we recommend using Qt::qInstallMessageHandler() instead.` Maybe you want to replace this in the source code and try again?

Comment: I have a new error http://pastebin.com/VxL2iCV9

Comment: Sorry, I guess I can't help you with that. Maybe just comment that line out, it seems to be unimportant for you (unless you need QxtDaemon). But I can't believe you're the only one who wants libqxt / Qt5 under Ubuntu ;)

Comment: Yeah... I can try that... Or I should just wait. Maybe it will be fixed in the further releases. (: Anyway - thank you for help (:

Comment: Well, as far as I know, qxt development is pretty much dead...

Comment: [Well, it seems like I was wrong about that.](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/commits/all)

Answer (score 1):

I am now facing a similar problem on Ubuntu 13.10 and I have succeeded in compiling my application. The problem is a SIGSEGV I receive when adding the logger engine

```
QxtBasicFileLoggerEngine *dbg  = new QxtBasicFileLoggerEngine("debug.log");

// qxtLog takes ownership of dbg - no need to manage its memory
qxtLog->addLoggerEngine("dbg", dbg);
```

In order to do this I compiled everything with QT4 from command line (Don't use qmake, which uses by default qt5):

```
qmake-qt4 
make
```

So this seems to be indeed a weird combination of qt5 libs with qt4 libs (libqxt seems to be compiled with/for qt4). Unfortunately I don't have any other option that to use qt4 in order to compile the project on Ubuntu. I don't know if there's an issue raised at canonical.

Hope this saves some trouble and eliminates some frustration. I am surprised to see that almost nobody complains about this problem.